# Error when using normc and normr

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, when I create a simple matrix, for example:

```
a = [1 2;3 4];
```

then I can use normc(a) or normr(a). However, when I load a grayscale image into Matlab, these functions always throw error:

> Error using  .*  Integers can only be combined with integers of the
>   same class, or scalar doubles.

Following is my image. Can you help fix?

[image]

Comment: It would be weird for that command to (i) throw an error if it works for a simple array, and (ii) to throw *that* error. Please (i) make sure that the problem is not somewhere else, maybe provide some context (ii) make sure your image is indeed greyscale, i.e. is a 2d array, (iii) try casting your integer-valued image to `double` by `normc(double(a))`.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Many functions don't support integer types. Just convert to double precision with `double`.

Comment: @horchler don't you think it's a bit odd that `normc` doesn't check for the type internally? Being a convenience function and all...

Comment: If I add double(a) then it works.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Not really. Many functions behave like this. Also, `normr` and `normc` are in the Neural Network toolbox.